# Redirect from one directory to another with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The following is my directory structures:

```
admin\
controls\
images\
media\
lib\
models\
views\
index.php
.htaccess
```

The following is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule /admin/images/(.*) /images/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
```

I want everything in /admin/images be equal to /images in root directory. For example: http://www.example.com/admin/images/example.png will be the same as http://www.example.com/images/example.png

**Problem with my .htaccess is:**
It goes to index.php instead of mirroring admin/images to images/

---

**Solution**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule /admin/images/(.*) /images/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
```

Comment: It goes to index.php instead of mirroring admin/images to images/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify that your image rewrite rule is the last one in the row in order to prevent further rewriting. For that you simply specify `[L]` at the end of your image rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule /admin/images/(.*) /images/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
```

**EDIT:** Here is an explanation why the problem occurs (taken from the comments section in order to provide clarification).

You see the original `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` will never change no matter how many stages of rewriting are performed. That means that when the second rule is reached that variable will actually still point to the existing image (which is in `/admin/images/`) rather to the one being rewritten and non-existing (`/images/`). That's the reason why the second rule will always be applied and why the two conditional lines from the example are almost always the first ones to be used during rewriting.

Comment: I was stupid. I tried [L] once (maybe I forgot to save that time and it didn't work). Thanks you so much. It is working now.

Comment: Sorry, I would like to understand, too. The RewriteCond say that the last rule has to be applied only if the requested file isn't a file or a directory... isn't an image a file (assuming that the image exists)?

Comment: You are correct but there is a tiny trick hidden in these rules which is responsible for confusion :) You see the original `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` will **never** change no matter how many stages of rewriting are performed. That means that when the second rule is reached that variable will actually still point to the existing image (which is in `/admin/images/`) rather to the one being rewritten and non-existing (`/images/`). That's the reason why the second rule will always be applied and why the two conditional lines from the example are almost always the first ones to be used during rewriting.

Comment: @holodoc: Just another quick question from someone aso trying to understand. If %{REQUEST_FILENAME} points to an existing image, won't the first RewriteCond fail (!-f) and thus the RewriteRule won't be applied?

Answer (score 4):

Change the rule as follow:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^admin/images/(.*) images/$1
```

And put your .htaccess in your document root, or however in the '/admin' parent folder.

Comment: I tried and it did not work. I put in document root and admin folder as well. Anyway, thanks for answering my question. +1

Comment: Quite strange. Have a look to http://www.francescoruvolo.it/test/admin/images/. It works perfectly on my server. I don't have any index.html in /test/admin/images while I have one on test/images. Are your httpd.conf allowing the use of .htaccess?

Comment: The problem is my other RewriteRule overrides this RewriteRule. Adding [L] simply solve the problem.

Comment: I saw... But actually I don't understand why that rules should override this one... an image file shouldn't match RewriteCond conditions. I have your same .htaccess in that folder... it redirects me on index.php only if I ask for a not existing file. Maybe holodoc could explain it to me. :)

Comment: Perfect! no `/` needed in front.