# 100% mirror one directory from another with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mirror

I want that `domain.tld/en/` is a 100% mirror for `domain.tld/` with all its (sub-)directories and files but does not change its URL for the client. Currently the PHP files can't access all their needed files (like CSS) because they can't find them in `domain.tld/en/css/file.css` (just in `/css/file.css` which should be the same)

This is what my .htaccess looks like right now (adapted from another question (see below)):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule /en/(.*) /$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
```

### Background

I can't find a solution for my problem on stackoverflow.
Its very near to this question [Redirect from one directory to another with mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273608/redirect-from-one-directory-to-another-with-mod-rewrite), but because I don't really understand how to modify htaccess files it doesn't help me, sadly.

I have a website running in the index.php of a main directory e.g. `domain.tld/index.php`, now I have modified the php file with replaceable strings for multilingual content and a detection in which directory its used in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be any difference between files in the root directory and files in other directories. try this one (note that I've added `L` flag which will make the `mod_rewrite` stop looking for other rules when the first one was matched (in your case any file under `en/` should have match both the first and the second rules - so it would apply both rewrites

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\/?en\/(.*) $1?lang=en [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
```