# Redirect from one path to another using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Redirect from one path to another using htaccess

I have some urls like these:-

```
https://www.example.com/au/path1

https://www.example.com/sg/path1

https://www.example.com/ca/path1
```

and many more, I want to redirect these url to this type :-

```
https://www.example.com/au/path2

https://www.example.com/sg/path2

https://www.example.com/ca/path2
```

But I am not getting desired result, here is my code :-

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} path1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/path2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Are you using any specific framework ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect from one directory to another with mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273608/redirect-from-one-directory-to-another-with-mod-rewrite)

Comment: @TismonVarghese:- I am using drupal 6.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/path1$ /$1/path2 [L]`

Comment: Does any redirect work? If you put these commands in a `.htaccess` file you need to have `AllowOverride` to have `All` or `FileInfo` in the virtual host configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the prefix of the request uri and use that to make the redirection. Something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/path1$ $1/path2 [R=301,L]
```

*Update:*

If you have a continuously changing set of aliases that you need to redirect, you might want to look into [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html). This module allows you to have different external sources to provide the map for the rewrites.

You can, for example have a text file with key, value pairs:

```
foo/bar /foo-new/bar
bar/foo /bar/foo-new
```

Then have a rewrite rule in combination with this map:

```
RewriteMap examplemap "txt:/path/to/file/map.txt"
RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "${examplemap:$1}"
```

Then you can make sure to update this file (in case from Drupal) whenever the map needs to change. Apache will look at the modification time of the file and flush the cache if it has changed.

You can also use an external application or use some other improved resources.

Comment: Without space before '[' all switches in path, With one - receive full server path

Comment: @splash58, thank you, the space was indeed missing. Otherwise works for me.

Comment: @splash58, not redirecting anywhere. :(

Comment: what's your apache version? for me it worked as from `http://example.com/foo/test1` got redirected to `http://example.com/foo/test2` and `http://example.com/bar/test1` to `http://example.com/bar/test2`

Comment: @sumitjainjr the answer or code from my comment to question?

Comment: @fejese: I am using drupal 6 ,  Apache/2.2.29 , PHP Version 5.3.29. Here I am trying to do-  ` RewriteRule ^(.*)/path1$ /$1/path2  [R=301,L]`

Comment: @fejese :- here I would like to clarify that in my url  "https://www.example.com/ca/path1" , 'ca' and 'path1' is not a directory or subdirectory. this is randomly i am getting by drupal function. this is just a path.

Comment: @sumitjainjr: do you have a list of these? Or do you want dynamic mapping? If so, do you want apache to handle it, or drupal?

Comment: @fejese: Yeah I have a list of these but this list is very big and changes time to time. so I just need to do is that, if someone trying to access "https://www.example.com/ca/path1" will be redirected to "https://www.example.com/ca/path2" all part will be the same, if anything comes before 'path1', simple its just redirected to 'path2'. And all I need to handle this from htaccess. In this url only 'ca','au', 'sg' will be replaced. 'path1' and 'path2' is fixed.

Comment: @sumitjainjr, did you try `RewriteMap` (see update in my answer)?

Comment: @fejese: Thanks for your response. But I managed this thing in some other way (by changing my module) due to short time of span. But Literally thanks from bottom of my heart. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to redirect these urls one by one is Redirect directive of [Apache mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) .

Try this in your root/.htaccess file :

```
RedirectPermanent /au/path1 /au/path2
RedirectPermanent /sg/path1 /sg/path2
RedirectPermanent /ca/path1 /ca/path2
```

You can change **RedirectPermanent** to **RedirectTemp** for temporary redirect.

Comment: These ("/au/path1" "/au/path2") are not my directories or subdirectories, these path I am getting dynamically. so I can't add one by one.

Comment: RedirectMatch ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/path2